# the issues of column type in read.table result and their transformation

Tags: r

I read a csv file as follows

```
dataBU<-read.table("data1.csv",sep=",",header=T,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

the data looks like as follows

```
  id   q1  q2   q3   q4 
  AB   1   1     0   1   
  AJ   0   2     3   0   
  AM   5   4     2   0  
  RA   2   1    10   0  
  BS   5   0     0   1
```

Then I would like to keep the last four columns, thus I have

```
dataBu1<-dataBu[,2:5]
```

But when I check the data, I found

```
> dataBu1[1,1]
 [1] 1

> dataBu1[1,2]
 [1] "1"
```

The first column and the second column are of different types. The first column is of numeric type and the second column is of character type. I assume both of them should be of numeric type. But it turns out that it is not true. What  causes this kind of scenario and how to transform the second column into the type of numeric.

Comment: Perhaps there is a character value in one of the numeric columns later in the dataset.

Comment: @user297850 Check if `sum(!grepl("^[0-9]+$", dataBu1[,2]))>0` returns `TRUE`

Comment: also, you might want to try using `fread`:   `library(data.table);  fread("data1.csv")`

Comment: try `colClasses` option with `read.table`.

Comment: @akrun, could you give me some explanation on the reason of checking sum(!grepl("^[0-9]+$", dataBu1[,2]))>0? What does "^[0-9]+$" do?

Comment: @user297850  It was just a preliminary check to look for elements other than numbers (assuming that you don't have decimals).  `^[0-9]$`matches elements that contain only numbers from the start `^` to the end `$`  `grepl` returns a logical index of those elements and by negating `!` you are looking for elements that are not numbers.  Take the sum, if it is `>0`, you would know that there are such elements in your column.  But, you don't need this if you use `as.numeric` or use the other suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose if you have `character` values in a `numeric` column, one way to convert it back to `numeric` is to use `as.numeric`

```
 set.seed(42)
 dataBu1 <- data.frame(q1=sample(1:10,20,replace=TRUE),
         q2=sample(c('', 5:15,'q2'),20,replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

 as.numeric(dataBu1[,2]) #replace all the character values with NA but it issues a warning message
#[1] 14  5 15 15 NA 10  8 14  9 14 12 13  8 12 NA 13 NA  6 14 11
#Warning message:
#NAs introduced by coercion
```

for multiple columns (assuming that you read the dataset with `stringsAsFactors=FALSE`)

```
 dataBu1[] <-lapply(dataBu1, as.numeric)
 str(dataBu1)
 #'data.frame': 20 obs. of  2 variables:
 #$ q1: num  10 10 3 9 7 6 8 2 7 8 ...
 #$ q2: num  15 5 NA NA 5 10 9 15 9 14 ...
```

Or without getting the warning message

```
 dataBu1[] <- lapply(dataBu1, function(x) 
            as.numeric(replace(x, !grepl("^[0-9]+$", x), NA)))
```

#### Update

I guess you are asking to find the index of non-numeric elements after it was read using `read.table`.

```
  lapply(dataBu1, function(x) which(!grepl("^[0-9]+$", x)))
  #$q1
  #integer(0)

  #$q2
  #[1]  3  4 15 17
```

Comment: thanks, by the way, is there a way to check before hand which element in dataBu1[,2] is character, which causes the problem?

Comment: @user297850  I guess you want the index of non-numeric elements.  I updated.